Windows batch to compare two file names with partial mismatch
I have a directory with video files and their corresponding (hidden) .idx files. When deleting any video files the corresponding .idx files remain. I want to periodically delete these "unassociated" .idx files.
The batch script below achieves this, but it only works when the .idx file name matches the video file name. ie: One.mts and One.idx.
The problem is that when created, the .idx files have a Video file extension appended to their name. Hence, I have One.mts and One.mts.idx.
How can I get the code to compare the two names whilst ignoring the additional appended extension in the .idx file.
The best solution would be if I could get the code to ignore the .idx part of the file whilst still comparing these two files. This would enable other video types to be stored in the same directory without their .idx files being deleted because they did not match the .mts video file name (I think).
FYI: The fact the .idx files are hidden is not an issue with the code below.
@echo off
   echo.
   echo.

for %%F in ("*.idx") do @if not exist "%%~nF.mts" echo "%%F"
   echo.
   echo.

set /p my_var= Press ENTER To Delete...Click X to Cancel

   for %%F in (*.idx) do @if not exist "%%~nF.mts" del "%%F"


Just to make sure I understood your question even with my cognitive difficulties in languages ​​other than my native language...
Consider that I have a folder with the following files...
.\001.mts.idx
.\002.idx
.\002.mts
.\003.mts.idx
.\004.idx
.\004.mts
.\005.mts.idx
.\006.idx
.\006.mts
.\007.mts.idx
.\008.idx
.\008.mts
.\009.mts.idx
.\010.idx
.\011.mts.idx
.\012.idx


To create these files for my tests, I created them in an empty folder and ran the bat below:
@echo off
  
cd /d "%~dp0"
  
>.\001.mts.idx   echo/001.mts.idx
>.\002.idx       echo/002.idx
>.\002.mts       echo/002.mts
>.\003.mts.idx   echo/003.mts.idx
>.\004.idx       echo/004.idx
>.\004.mts       echo/004.mts
>.\005.mts.idx   echo/005.mts.idx
>.\006.idx       echo/006.idx
>.\006.mts       echo/006.mts
>.\007.mts.idx   echo/007.mts.idx
>.\008.idx       echo/008.idx
>.\008.mts       echo/008.mts
>.\009.mts.idx   echo/009.mts.idx
>.\010.idx       echo/010.idx
>.\011.mts.idx   echo/011.mts.idx
>.\012.idx       echo/012.idx


Now with these files in a folder, not being sure of their objective or scenario, I tried using a for /f loop filtering only the files where any_name.mts.idx, This is because the where command can list the files in this name layout by explicitly answering the names for wildcard use in the format *.mts.idx.
Since I already obtain the names of the files of interest in a loop, I just need to use the non-existent file conditional to perform the action of deleting your orphan file, so if the file current_name.mts does not exist, then I understand that it is for delete current_name.mts.idx...
@echo off && setlocal

cd /d "%~dp0"

for /f delims^= %%G in =;(' @"%__AppDir__%where.exe" .:*.mts.idx
   ');= do call set "_name=%%~nG" && call %:^) "%%_name:.idx=%%"

%:^)
if "%~1" == "" =;(
     "%windir%\System32\timeout.exe" -1 | endlocal & goto :eOf
    );= else if not exist ".\%~1" =;(
        echo/Deleting ".\%~1.idx" - file ".\%~n1.mts" not found!..
        @del /q /f /a ".\%~1.idx" & exit /b
    );= 

exit /b 


Batch outputs // by echo/Deleting ".\%~1" ... :

Deleting ".\001.mts.idx" - file ".\001.mts" not found!..
Deleting ".\003.mts.idx" - file ".\003.mts" not found!..
Deleting ".\005.mts.idx" - file ".\005.mts" not found!..
Deleting ".\007.mts.idx" - file ".\007.mts" not found!..
Deleting ".\009.mts.idx" - file ".\009.mts" not found!..
Deleting ".\011.mts.idx" - file ".\011.mts" not found!..


This only deals with the part of deleting the unmatched files where in the name you have AnyName.mts.idx, but if you have focused on receiving a response to deal with deleting the orphan names of any.idx and/or any.mts.idx. Then, you would have to use two For /F loops, the second with a specific filter to not handle occurrences of the name *.mts.idx, which can be obtained with find /aVoid...
@echo off && setlocal

cd /d "%~dp0"

for /f usebackq^delims^= %%G in =;(
    `"%windir%\System32\where.exe" .:*.mts.idx`
    );= do call set "_name=%%~nG" && call %:^) "%%_name:.idx=%%"

%:^)
if "%~1" == "" goto %:^(

if not exist ".\%~1" =;(
     echo/Deleting ".\%~1.idx" - file "%~1" not found!..
     @del /q /f /a ".\%~1.idx" & exit /b
    );= else goto :eOf

%:^(
for /f usebackq^delims^= %%i in =;(
    `call "%windir%\System32\where.exe" .:*.idx ^| "%windir%\System32\find.exe" /v /i ".mts.idx"`
    );= do if not exist ".\%%~ni.mts" =;(
          echo/Deleting ".\%%~ni.idx"     - file ".\%%~ni.mts" not found!..
          @del /q /f /a ".\%%~ni.idx"
        );=

"%windir%\System32\timeout.exe" -1 | endlocal & goto :eOf 


Batch outputs // by echo/Deleting ".\%~1.idx" |or| ".\%%~ni.idx" ... :

Deleting ".\001.mts.idx" - file ".\001.mts" not found!..
Deleting ".\003.mts.idx" - file ".\003.mts" not found!..
Deleting ".\005.mts.idx" - file ".\005.mts" not found!..
Deleting ".\007.mts.idx" - file ".\007.mts" not found!..
Deleting ".\009.mts.idx" - file ".\009.mts" not found!..
Deleting ".\011.mts.idx" - file ".\011.mts" not found!..
Deleting ".\010.idx"     - file ".\010.mts" not found!..
Deleting ".\012.idx"     - file ".\012.mts" not found!..



Note: Pay attention to the use of cd /d "%~dp0", where in this way, it makes the bat enter and work inside the folder where the bat itself is. If you save the batch in another folder other than the folder where you are going to test and/or perform the action of deleting your files, then replace it with the full path of the folder where you have the `*.mts, *.idx, *mts.idx the in the form:

@echo off && setlocal

cd /d "D:\The\Full\Path\To\Where\Your\Files\Are"
...


1. Define the use of what to return in the output command
do/from For /F "Delims=" .. (cmd), as without delimiter, so it will use the entire output line.
...
 
for /f delims^= %%G in (' ...
   ');= do ...


2. As already mentioned, where .:*.mts.idx will only return files that explicitly have the layout of the name met by the wildcard "any file in current folder = * " + ".String1" + ".String2"
...
for /f ... (' @"%__AppDir__%where.exe" .:*.mts.idx ') do ... 


3. Use the call set _varible=File_Name to define the name of the listed file in the current variable %~file_Name_from_G (%%~nG) in a loop, use the call set to define the name of the file listed in the current variable in a loop, and then use a call :Lable %%_variable_defined_and_already_expanded_on_the_same_line:SubString_remove/replace_String[.IDX]=[Nothing]% by %_name:.idx=[NOTHING!!!]%:
...

for /f ( ... 
   ) do call set "_name=%%~nG" && call %:^) "%%_name:.idx=%%"


4. Your flow will enter the :Label on 2 occasions, first through the call call :Label where you pass the argument 1 (%1) "%%_name:.idx=%%", and in a second moment when the loop finalizes the file listing within from For /F loop, at that moment there will be no call to the :Lable, and therefore, the argument %1 passage will not be true. Then the true condition will be satisfied by the call + argument 1 and the false condition will be satisfied when there is no call and no argument passed in the same processing event, thus arriving at the :Label in the order of the line in the batch.
When the :Label is not called, it goes to the :Secound_Label, if it is called, it in turn checks the existence of the Current_File_Name.mts and if it does not exist, it returns the .idx extension to delete the name of the sent file, in the form, delete Current_File_Name.mts.idx, and exits/returns from the :Label called with goto :End_Of_File (which is the same as exit /b), and similarly in this if, if the file exists, it comes out in ) else goto :eof
...

:Lable
if "%~1" == "" ( 
     goto :Secound_Label
   ) else if not exist ".\%~1" (
     echo/Deleting ".\%~1.idx" - file "%~1" not found!..
     @del /q /f /a ".\%~1.idx" & exit /b
    );= else goto :eOf 



5. The :Secound_Label will use the same mechanics/logic as the first :Lable, but will filter the files already treated in the first  For /F loop using the filter in the redirection | FindString /aVoid AnyFileThatContains_a_Name_With[.mts.idx], thus restricting execution only on files `Name_Any[.idx], and when no ".idx orfan file" is found, it will operate the exclusion...
...

:Secound_Label
for /f usebackq^delims^= %%i in =;(
    `call "%windir%\System32\where.exe" .:*.idx ^| "%windir%\System32\find.exe" /v /i ".mts.idx"`
    );= do if not exist ".\%%~ni.mts" =;(
          echo/Deleting ".\%%~ni.idx"     - file ".\%%~ni.mts" not found!..
          @del /q /f /a ".\%%~ni.idx"
        );=


6. The timeout -1 is a pause omitting the output with the regular text Press any key to continue ... and waiting to execute the commands by adding the pipe (redirection) | ends the Setlocal (with Endlocal) and goes to the end of the file, finishing the batch execution, but pauses for as long as the user desires and/or finds necessary to see the text displaying the names of the files excluded in the previous actions.
...

"%windir%\System32\timeout.exe" -1 | endlocal & goto :eOf 


Some further reading:

CD /?

Set /?

For /?

For /F /?

Find /?

Where /?

Find /?

Setlocal | Endlocal /?

Using: Conditional Execution

|| and &&


Where does GOTO :EOF return to?

Using: Commands with Redirection

|, <, >, 2>, 2>&1, etc.


Using: Set _Varibel=SubStrings=Replace%

What does %~dp0 mean, and how does it work?

An A-Z Index of Windows CMD commands on ss64.com



@ lo-ol.. Thankyou for your impressive contribution. I'm very new to batch and I'm currently trying to digest your reply... Will post back when I have a clearer understanding of the code you supplied.

@ lo-ol... Thankyou again for the additional info. Both scripts work exactly as I described.
The first script will cover almost all situations I use, because so far every IDX file has had an appended extension. The only ommission (in both scripts) is the ability to search subdirectories (I forgot to include the /r switch when typing my original script). With your additional info I am sure I can figure that one out for the solutions you provided. Awesome work...Thanks again.

In my next free time I will look at an option that handles multiplicities of video extension variations. I think this is your need, right?

@ lo-ol... That would be far more than I hoped for. I thought I could just run seperate scripts for different formats, but a single script would be awesome. Look forward to seeing if it's possible. Thankyou again.

You could something like this, if no corresponding video file is found it asks if you want to delete the idx (file\s)...
@echo off

:: Inform the folder where the videos and idx files are:
set Folder=%userprofile%\desktop\Teste

echo Would you like to delete this Files?

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b "%Folder%\*.idx"') do for /f "tokens=*" %%b in ("%%~na") do if not exist "%Folder%\%%~na.mts" if not exist "%Folder%\%%~nb.mts" echo %%a

set /p "Option=Press X to delete: "
IF /i "%Option%"=="x" goto :Delete

exit

:Delete
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b "%Folder%\*.idx"') do for /f "tokens=*" %%b in ("%%~na") do if not exist "%Folder%\%%~na.mts" if not exist "%Folder%\%%~nb.mts" del /q "%Folder%\%%a"
exit


@ Ricardo Bohner... Thankyou for the reply. Unfortunately this is not working for me...With tweaking I can get it to list all IDX files, but it does not discriminate at all.... I'm testing on win 7, so maybe it is an OS issue... I'm very new to batch so I maybe missing something... Will investigate further.

@ Richard Bohner...Appologies, my error. Works as expected. It appears that the way I had my video file directory linked to a different partition was causing issues. Removing the directory path from the script, so that it ran from a current directory rather than a named directory, solved the issue. I've updvoted your answer, but still hoping a solution can avoid deleting IDX files of other (non mts) video file formats. Thanks again.


@lo-ol... Thankyou again for the additional info. Both scripts work exactly as I described. The first script will cover almost all situations I use, because so far every IDX file has had an appended extension. The only ommission (in both scripts) is the ability to search subdirectories (I forgot to include the /r switch when typing my original script). With your additional info I am sure I can figure that one out for the solutions you provided. Awesome work...Thanks again. – Sark Commented15 hours ago
In my next free time I will look at an option that handles multiplicities of video extension variations. I think this is your need, right? –
Io-oI Commented 11 hours ago
@lo-ol... That would be far more than I hoped for. I thought I could just run separate scripts for different formats, but a single script would be awesome. Look forward to seeing if it's possible. Thankyou again. –
Sark Commented 7 hours ago


@echo off && setlocal && cd /d "%~dp0"

set "_eXtVD=aaf.idx asf.idx avi.idx bdmv.idx bik.idx clpi.idx cmf.idx cpi.idx dat.idx dav.idx divx.idx drc.idx m2p.idx"
set "_eXtVD=%_eXtVD% dts.idx dv.idx dvr-ms.idx f4v.idx fla.idx flv.idx gxf.idx h264.idx hevc.idx ismv.idx ivf.idx"
set "_eXtVD=%_eXtVD% mts.idx m2v.idx m4v.idx mkv.idx mod.idx mov.idx mp2.idx mp4.idx m1v.idx mp4v.idx mpe.idx"
set "_eXtVD=%_eXtVD% mpeg.idx mpg.idx mpl.idx mpls.idx mpsub.idx mpv.idx mts.idx mxf.idx ogg.idx ogm.idx"
set "_eXtVD=%_eXtVD% ogv.idx ps.idx qt.idx rm.idx rmvb.idx roq.idx nsv.idx rpl.idx smi.idx sml.idx"
set "_eXtVD=%_eXtVD% svi.idx swf.idx ts.idx tts.idx vob.idx"

for /f usebackq^ ^delims^= %%G in =;(` ^<nul ^<con: 2^>nul ^
    call "%%__AppDir__%%where.exe" /r . *.%%_eXtVD: ^= *.%%"
   `);= do ;@call %:^) "%%~nG" ".%%_eXtVD: = .%%" "%%~dpnxG"

%:^)
if "%~1" == "" =;( "%windir%\System32\timeout.exe" -1 | endlocal & goto :eOf 
    );= else set^ "_list=%~2" && call set^ "_list="%~n1%%_list: =" "%~n1%%""

for /r %%i in =;( %_list% );= do if exist "%%~dpi%%~ni" exit /b

echo/File "%~3" is orphaned! & echo/del /q /f /a: "%~3" & exit /b



Note (again): Pay attention to the use of cd /d "%~dp0", as this command ensures that the batch script enters and operates within the folder where the script itself is saved. The %_eXtVD% variable contains 60 predefined video extensions, including formats like .mts, .mp4, .avi, and others. These extensions will be used to perform operations on video files within the folder structure.

If the batch script is saved in a different folder from the root directory where the video files are organized in subfolders, you will need to replace the cd /d "%~dp0" command with the full path of the folder containing the video files. In this case, use the absolute path to the folder containing files such as *.mts, *.idx, *.mp4, or combined extensions like *.mts.idx. For example, replace cd /d "%~dp0" with something like:
@echo off && setlocal

cd /d "D:\The\Full\Path\To\Where\Root\Folder\Are"
...

This way, the script will correctly navigate to the root folder and perform the necessary actions on the video files distributed across subfolders.

1. I will use a replace substrings with the necessary escapes inside the for loop (^ in ^=) to transform the current value of the %_eXtVD% variable into and thus search for video extension files + .idx. *.%%_eXtVD: ^= *.%%
@echo off

...
for /f usebackq^ ^delims^= %%G in =;(` ^<nul ^<con: 2^>nul ^
    call "%%__AppDir__%%where.exe" /r . *.%%_eXtVD: ^= *.%%"
   `);= do ...


Outside the looping and on the command line, what has been composed for the variables and commands can be viewed with an echo and results in these outputs:

>echo/%_eXtVD%
aaf.idx asf.idx avi.idx bdmv.idx bik.idx clpi.idx cmf.idx cpi.idx dat.idx dav.idx divx.idx drc.idx m2p.idx dts.idx dv.idx dvr-ms.idx f4v.idx fla.idx flv.idx gxf.idx h264.idx hevc.idx ismv.idx ivf.idx mts.idx m2v.idx m4v.idx mkv.idx mod.idx mov.idx mp2.idx mp4.idx m1v.idx mp4v.idx mpe.idx mpeg.idx mpg.idx mpl.idx mpls.idx mpsub.idx mpv.idx mts.idx mxf.idx ogg.idx ogm.idx ogv.idx ps.idx qt.idx rm.idx rmvb.idx roq.idx nsv.idx rpl.idx smi.idx sml.idx svi.idx swf.idx ts.idx tts.idx vob.idx

>call "%%__AppDir__%%where.exe" /r . *.%%_eXtVD: = *.%%"
call "%C:\Windows\system32\%where.exe" /r . *.%aaf.idx *.asf.idx *.avi.idx *.bdmv.idx *.bik.idx *.clpi.idx *.cmf.idx *.cpi.idx *.dat.idx *.dav.idx *.divx.idx *.drc.idx *.m2p.idx *.dts.idx *.dv.idx *.dvr-ms.idx *.f4v.idx *.fla.idx *.flv.idx *.gxf.idx *.h264.idx *.hevc.idx *.ismv.idx *.ivf.idx *.mts.idx *.m2v.idx *.m4v.idx *.mkv.idx *.mod.idx *.mov.idx *.mp2.idx *.mp4.idx *.m1v.idx *.mp4v.idx *.mpe.idx *.mpeg.idx *.mpg.idx *.mpl.idx *.mpls.idx *.mpsub.idx *.mpv.idx *.mts.idx *.mxf.idx *.ogg.idx *.ogm.idx *.ogv.idx *.ps.idx *.qt.idx *.rm.idx *.rmvb.idx *.roq.idx *.nsv.idx *.rpl.idx *.smi.idx *.sml.idx *.svi.idx *.swf.idx *.ts.idx *.tts.idx *.vob.idx%"


2. In the Call to :Lable I will use the sending of the file name, where a crop is made just omitting the .idx extension by using the dynamically expanded variable, thus sending only the Name (%%~nG) as the first argument (%~1 == %%~G), already the second (%~2 == ".%%_eXtVD: = .%%"), then a new replace just adding a "." before each item/value within the variable, and finally, I am sending the full file path listed in a recursive loop as a third argument (%~3 == %%~dpnxG):
....

for /f ... in (` cmd_loop ) do call :Lable "%%~nG" ".%%_eXtVD: = .%%" "%%~dpnxG"

....


Outside the looping and on the command line, what has been composed for the variables and commands can be viewed with an echo and results in these outputs:

>echo/ call :Lable "%%~nG"
 call :Lable "Some_File_in_Loop.mpeg"

>call echo/".%%_eXtVD: = .%%"
".aaf.idx .asf.idx .avi.idx .bdmv.idx .bik.idx .clpi.idx .cmf.idx .cpi.idx .dat.idx .dav.idx .divx.idx .drc.idx .m2p.idx .dts.idx .dv.idx .dvr-ms.idx .f4v.idx .fla.idx .flv.idx .gxf.idx .h264.idx .hevc.idx .ismv.idx .ivf.idx .mts.idx .m2v.idx .m4v.idx .mkv.idx .mod.idx .mov.idx .mp2.idx .mp4.idx .m1v.idx .mp4v.idx .mpe.idx .mpeg.idx .mpg.idx .mpl.idx .mpls.idx .mpsub.idx .mpv.idx .mts.idx .mxf.idx .ogg.idx .ogm.idx .ogv.idx .ps.idx .qt.idx .rm.idx .rmvb.idx .roq.idx .nsv.idx .rpl.idx .smi.idx .sml.idx .svi.idx .swf.idx .ts.idx .tts.idx .vob.idx"

>echo/"%%~dpnxG"
"C:\Users\ecker\Desktop\SU2024\Q1855875\Sub Dir 001\Sub Dir 002\Some_File_in_Loop.mpeg.idx"

Note Obviously I did a split to echo the argument line by line of the three arguments directed to the call :Label and thus improving the example and visualization of the mechanics and results used.

3. Here is a new replace substrings just adding/replacing the blank spaces with double quotes (" + file_name) before each dot [ext1.ext2] already added in the Call to the :Label by call argument 2, and thus preparing the variable strings for use within the next loop.
set "_list=%~2" && call set "_list="%~n1%%_list: =" "%~n1%%""


Outside the looping and on the command line, what has been composed for the variables and commands can be viewed with an echo and results in these outputs:

>echo/"%_list%"
"Some_File_in_Loop.aaf.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.asf.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.avi.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.bdmv.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.bik.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.clpi.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.cmf.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.cpi.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.dat.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.dav.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.divx.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.drc.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.m2p.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.dts.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.dv.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.dvr-ms.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.f4v.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.fla.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.flv.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.gxf.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.h264.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.hevc.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.ismv.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.ivf.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.mts.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.m2v.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.m4v.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.mkv.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.mod.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.mov.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.mp2.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.mp4.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.m1v.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.mp4v.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.mpe.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.mpeg.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.mpg.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.mpl.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.mpls.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.mpsub.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.mpv.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.mts.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.mxf.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.ogg.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.ogm.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.ogv.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.ps.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.qt.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.rm.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.rmvb.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.roq.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.nsv.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.rpl.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.smi.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.sml.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.svi.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.swf.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.ts.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.tts.idx" "Some_File_in_Loop.vob.idx"


4. At this point the variable string and the "mass" composition of the passed name plus all possible extension variations will be used in the recursive search for a file current_name_current_extension (without the .idx), and here only if any file in this name layout is found, the loop is aborted as there is no necessary action, and thus preserving the file from being deleted obeying if it exists run from there!
for /r %%i in ( %_list% ) do if exist "%%~dpi%%~ni" exit /b


5 For the file argument %~3, which is received inside the label with the value of the full path to the file and is used with its possible variations for name parity searches in different video formats and for different folders, if this file does not have its corresponding pair, then it is time to delete it, otherwise, the previous loop would not allow aborting before this stage/processing is executed.
echo/File "%~3" is orphaned! & echo/del /q /f /a: "%~3" & exit /b


6 You can see that an echo/del ... was intentionally added, so it is possible to do a test run beforehand, and if the output is correct, just remove the echo/ so that it is executed to effectively delete your orphaned files.
@echo off

...

echo/File "%~3" is orphaned! & echo/del /q /f /a: "%~3" & exit /b
echo/File "%~3" is orphaned! & echo/del /q /f /a: "%~3" & exit /b
echo/File "%~3" is orphaned! &      del /q /f /a: "%~3" & exit /b

-// Edit //-

Script created to create/reproduce the scene/environment with the function of creating folder tree and randomly creating Files.VideoExtencion with and or without (randomly) the final ending (.eXtension) **.idx:

@echo off && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

cd /d "%~dp0" && for /L %%L in =;( 0000,0001,0003 )=; do for /L %%l in =;( 0000,0001,0003 
     )=; do echo/%%l%%L%%l %%L%%l%%L %%l%%L%%l | >nul findstr /v "000 111 222 333" && =;(
          call rem./ & mkdir ".\Dir %%~l%%~L%%~l\Dir %%~L%%~l%%~L\Dir %%~l%%~L%%~l" 1>nul
         )=;

timeout 1 | call echo/"%__cd__%"

set "_eXtVD=aaf.idx asf.idx avi.idx bdmv.idx bik.idx clpi.idx cmf.idx cpi.idx dat.idx dav.idx divx.idx drc.idx m2p.idx"
set "_eXtVD=%_eXtVD% dts.idx dv.idx dvr-ms.idx f4v.idx fla.idx flv.idx gxf.idx h264.idx hevc.idx ismv.idx ivf.idx"
set "_eXtVD=%_eXtVD% mts.idx m2v.idx m4v.idx mkv.idx mod.idx mov.idx mp2.idx mp4.idx m1v.idx mp4v.idx mpe.idx"
set "_eXtVD=%_eXtVD% mpeg.idx mpg.idx mpl.idx mpls.idx mpsub.idx mpv.idx mts.idx mxf.idx ogg.idx ogm.idx"
set "_eXtVD=%_eXtVD% ogv.idx ps.idx qt.idx rm.idx rmvb.idx roq.idx nsv.idx rpl.idx smi.idx sml.idx"
set "_eXtVD=%_eXtVD% svi.idx swf.idx ts.idx tts.idx vob.idx" & set /a "_rand=!random! %% 2"

for /r /d %%i in =;( * 
     );= do cd /d "%%~dpnxi" && =;(
          for %%G in =;( %_eXtVD% );= do =;(
          if !_rand! equ 1 =;(
              call set^ "_file_Name=File_%%random%%"
              @echo/ ".\%%~G" >"%%~dpnxi\!_file_Name!.%%~G"
              @echo/  Created: "%%~dpnxi\!_file_Name!.%%~G"
             );=
          set /a "_rand=!random! %% 2"
          if !_rand! equ 1 =;(
              call set^ "_file_Name=File_%%random%%"
              @echo/ ".\%%~G" >"%%~dpnxi\!_file_Name!.%%~G"
              @echo/  Created: "%%~dpnxi\!_file_Name!.%%~G"
             );=
         );=
         
     for %%I in =;( *.idx );= do =;(
          if !_rand! equ 1 =;(
              call set^ "_Name_idx=%%~nI"
              call set^ "_eXt_File=%%~xI"
              call set^ "_eXt_File=!_eXt_File:~0,-4!"
              @echo/ ".\%%~I" >"%%~dpnxi\!_Name_idx!!_eXt_File!"
              @echo/  Created: "%%~dpnxi\!_Name_idx!!_eXt_File!"
             );=
          set /a "_rand=!random! %% 2"
         );=
    );= 
    
timeout -1 | =;( echo/ & echo/  iS dOnE! & echo/ );= & endlocal


Script output:

"C:\Users\ecker\Desktop\SU2024\Q1855875\"   // current folder (test)
  Created: "C:\Users\ecker\Desktop\SU2024\Q1855875\Dir 010\File_27463.aaf.idx"
  Created: "C:\Users\ecker\Desktop\SU2024\Q1855875\Dir 010\File_13934.bdmv.idx"
  Created: "C:\Users\ecker\Desktop\SU2024\Q1855875\Dir 010\File_21003.bik.idx"
  ... 
  ...  //    Many lines reporting file created...
  ...
  Created: "C:\Users\ecker\Desktop\SU2024\Q1855875\Dir 323\Dir 232\Dir 323\File_8252.divx"
  Created: "C:\Users\ecker\Desktop\SU2024\Q1855875\Dir 323\Dir 232\Dir 323\File_8978.ps"
  Created: "C:\Users\ecker\Desktop\SU2024\Q1855875\Dir 323\Dir 232\Dir 323\File_9427.ogg"

  iS dOnE!


Tree created during execution where the files (seriously, several of them) will be created recursively:

>tree . /a 
+---Dir 010
|   \---Dir 101
|       \---Dir 010
+---Dir 020
|   \---Dir 202
|       \---Dir 020
+---Dir 030
|   \---Dir 303
|       \---Dir 030
+---Dir 101
|   \---Dir 010
|       \---Dir 101
+---Dir 121
|   \---Dir 212
|       \---Dir 121
+---Dir 131
|   \---Dir 313
|       \---Dir 131
+---Dir 202
|   \---Dir 020
|       \---Dir 202
+---Dir 212
|   \---Dir 121
|       \---Dir 212
+---Dir 232
|   \---Dir 323
|       \---Dir 232
+---Dir 303
|   \---Dir 030
|       \---Dir 303
+---Dir 313
|   \---Dir 131
|       \---Dir 313
\---Dir 323
    \---Dir 232
        \---Dir 323


@lo-ol... Firstly, thanks for the stirling work with this thread. Appologies for the late response. I had an issue that I have been trying to resolve before replying. I now know the script works exactly as per my request.... However >>>




when testing I used your original file creation script. This included some orphan idx files that did not include video extensions in their names, these were not being deleted. It took me longer than it
should have to realise why. Not an issue,because all my idx file names will include video extensions (the reason for my original post). Producing my own creation script, with file extensions applied to all idx files, confirmed the source of the problem.... Thanks again, it's appreciated.




I thank you for all your actions, I beg your forgiveness, I didn't understand your comment here, again it's my fault! The part about the time/delay in commenting, I understood that part, and that's not a problem or discomfort for me. Please consider using the time you have/available without rushing and/or committing.

I will share with you the script I created to create a tree of folders/subfolders and the randomly orphan/non-orphan files which I used to reproduce the environment and I can create the recursive script for you... >>>




I believe that, in some way, I can edit and adapt to any action and/or correction that may be necessary to better serve you.  This way you can create a folder and put the script inside it (or adjust cd /d "D:\Path\To\Root\Folder"), and when running the folders and files will be created recursively for testing purposes. /your adaptations, and if necessary, some editing by me too




@ lo-ol... To clarify my comment. If  name.mts.idx is an orphan it "is" deleted.  If name.idx  is an orphan, it is "not" deleted. This is "not" an issue for me. All my idx files have a video file extension appended to their name. Your final script works perfectly for me.

@ lo-ol... There is one adaptation I have been unable to impliment. If I want to include an option to press the D key to Delete, or C key to Cancel, I can use  the choice /c command, in combination with goto %errorlevel%. Unfortunately, when I impliment this option the loop stops searching after finding the first orphan idx file. How do I impliment choice /c after all orphan idx files have been found and listed.

Just following up, I continue testing options here...

I'm using your folder tree creation script to carry out some tests myself.  I have discovered that wildcard idx naming set "_eXtVD=*.idx can speed processing up considerably. Cannot yet confirm if the results match the output from fully naming all idx video extension types.

as the extension mts was mentioned and somehow suggested to have more extensions and not explained which ones, I defined in the variable only 60 video extensions that I found in searches... d:)

@ lo-ol... To clarify... Your current script works perfectly. If it is possible to offer an option to Delete, or Cancel, after the list is displayed in the command window, this would be even better... I have confused the discussion by commenting on a different aspect of the scripts function.... >>>




I discovered that just using *.idx in the deletion script, (instead of listing all 60 video extensions) produces the same result, but is much quicker. This was more a comment/observation than a question. Appologies for distracting from the main topic...:)




Hi there! Please let me know if this sounds good to you. It's about 98% complete, and I'm currently testing it. Check out the material in the link!

I'm new to batch and have zero experience of powershell, but I can see the versatility of introducing an option dialogue (including multiple related commands from a single script). Very interesting.
